# DocuSign PHP SDK - How Do I Populate Existing Text Tabs Programmatically?

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign PHP SDK and I would like to fill in values for existing text tabs / fields on my template.

I've tried using the following:

```
$textTab = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text();
$textTab->setTabId('f432a532-327e-4335-39ff-fk3285d732pd');
$textTab->setValue('3333 Kingman Ave');
$tabs = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
$tabs->setTextTabs(array($textTab));
$templateRole->setTabs($tabs);
```

where the parameter passed to `setTabId()` is taken from the **tabId** property of an object from the **textTabs** array in the template JSON export.

I've also tried using

```
$textTab->setTabLabel('corresponding-label-id')
```

in place of

```
$textTab->setTabId()
```

Neither changes the value in the tab they refer to.  What's the correct syntax to set a custom value for an existing text tab using the PHP SDK?

Comment: is 'corresponding-label-id' a tab label in your template which you are referring while create an envelope?

Comment: @AmitKBist Yes, it's a tab label on the document

Comment: Can you please capture and share the DS API logs which your application is creating when calling DocuSign platform, you can capture logs by following steps as explained [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging). Please make sure you enable logging with the credentials which you are using in your application.

Answer (score 0):

See example [EG017SetTemplateTabValues.php](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant/blob/master/src/EG017SetTemplateTabValues.php)

You set the values via the role object for the signer/recipient.

Eg

```
    # create the envelope definition with the template_id
    $envelope_definition = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition([
        'status' => 'sent', 'template_id' => $args['template_id']
    ]);
    # Set the values for the fields in the template
    $check1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Checkbox([
        'tab_label' => 'ckAuthorization', 'selected' => "true"]);
    $number1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Number([
        'tab_label' => "numbersOnly", 'value' => '54321']);
    $radio_group = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RadioGroup(['group_name' => "radio1",
        # You only need to provide the radio entry for the entry you're selecting
        'radios' => [
            new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Radio(['value' => "white", 'selected' => "true"]),
        ]]);
    $text = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text([
        'tab_label' => "text", 'value' => "Jabberwocky!"]);
    # Pull together the existing tabs in a Tabs object:
    $tabs = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs([
        'checkbox_tabs' => [$check1, $check3], 'number_tabs' => [$number1],
        'radio_group_tabs' => [$radio_group], 'text_tabs' => [$text]]);
    # Create the template role elements to connect the signer and cc recipients
    # to the template
    $signer = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\TemplateRole([
        'email' => $args['signer_email'], 'name' => $args['signer_name'],
        'role_name' => 'signer',
        'tabs' => $tabs # Set tab values
    ]);
    # Create a cc template role.
    $cc = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\TemplateRole([
        'email' => $args['cc_email'], 'name' => $args['cc_name'],
        'role_name' => 'cc'
    ]);
    # Add the TemplateRole objects to the envelope object
    $envelope_definition->setTemplateRoles([$signer, $cc]);
    return $envelope_definition;
```

Comment: Same result.  I have debugging turned on and the JSON returned shows the `tabs` object with the passed in label and value: `"tabs":{"textTabs":[{"tabLabel":"testtwo","value":"34433 wwwwwaa"}]}`.  Is there a settings option either on the template itself or associated API / integrator key that prevents custom fields from being set through API calls?

Comment: There are no settings like you suggest. I suggest that you not use account custom tabs. Try with regular tabs first. First get [eg-03-php-auth-code-grant](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant) running and see how it sets the template tabs' values. Then update it to your use case.

Comment: Also, update your question with your request's json.